# Bounded square integrable functions almost sure left-continuous in $L^{2}$ norm?

Tags: integration, limits, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to understand the construction of the Ito integral in Section 4.3 of Kuo "Introduction to Stochastic integration", but there is one point where I am stuck: For a stochastic process $f:[a,b]\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ (adapted to some filtration) which is square integrable, $\int_a^b E (|f(t,\cdot)|^2)dt<\infty$, and bounded, the author states for a $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$, $\tau\geq0$ (with $f(t)$ understood to be zero for $t<a$):

> Since $f$ is assumed to be bounded, we have $$\int_a^b|f(t,\cdot)-f(t-\frac{\tau}{n},\cdot)|^2dt\to0\text{ almost surely},$$ as $n\to\infty$.

I could understand this line if $f$ would be continuous in $t$, but this is explicitly not the case. Can someone explain?

Comment: Why is  $f(t-\tau/n, \cdot)$ defined?

Comment: I added that $f(t)$ is understood to be zero for $t<a$.

Comment: The claim holds if $t \mapsto f(t,\omega)$ is Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing more than the fact that translation is continuous on $L^2$, applied to the function $f_\omega: t\mapsto f(t,\omega)$ for a fixed $\omega$. As you observe, this is clear if $f_\omega$ is continuous. But any square-integrable function on the line can be approximated in the $L^2$ norm by a sequence of continuous functions of compact support.